# Сохранение данных при перезагрузке страницы (JS localStorage)

Tags: javascript

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, добавил localStorage. Все клики сохраняются в локальном хранилище после перезагрузки, но не выводится сохраненное число кликов на сайт. После перезагрузки значение 0 а должно быть то которое сохранено в  localStorage.

```
<div class="balance__container">
    <div id="clicks-count" class="balance">0.000</div>
</div>
<div id="big-btn" class="poiner">
    <div draggable="false" class="pointer__img"></div>
</div>


var clicks = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('clicks') || 0);

const onClick = () => {
    document.getElementById('clicks-count').innerText = (clicks + clickPower).toFixed(3);
    clicks = clicks + clickPower;
    updateStorage(clicks);

    console.info(localStorage.getItem('clicks'));
}

function updateStorage(clicks) {
    localStorage.setItem('clicks-count', clicks);
}

document.getElementById('big-btn').addEventListener('click', onClick)
```

Comment: `localStorage.setItem('clicks-count', clicks);` заменить на -> `localStorage.setItem('clicks', clicks);` (В фукнции `updateStorage`)

Comment: Пробовал, все равно при перезагрузки страницы 0, а в localStorage появляется Ключ - clicks с значением которое я накликаю, после перезагрузки значение остается. Но если сделать еще раз клик то значение обнуляется